# Opening form with DoCmd.OpenForm

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am troubleshooting and found that a button
[image]

does not seem to be working.

I want the button to print a report (from rptHerstelfiche) with the "IDDefect" as "Volgnr" (in rptHerstelfiche).

The code linked to that button.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Knop164_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Afdrukken_technische_gegevens_Click

    Dim stDocName As String
    
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
    stDocName = "rptHerstelfiche"
    'DoCmd.OpenReport "report name", acViewPreview,
    DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview, , "Volgnr=" & Me.IDDefect

Exit_Afdrukken_technische_gegevens_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Afdrukken_technische_gegevens_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Afdrukken_technische_gegevens_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the Click event property have [Event Procedure]? Have you set a breakpoint and step debugged?

Comment: Is Volgnr field name?

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks good, but a few things:

Because the current reocrd is being sent to the report? Then the current reocrd may NOT yet have been saved. So what you see in the report will not show what you have in the form.

I suggest this code. and the "select" record is not required.

```
Dim stDocName As String

if me.Dirty = True then me.Dirty = False  ' force data save
stDocName = "rptHerstelfiche"
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acPreview, , "Volgnr=" & Me.IDDefect
```

The last line looks a bit "suspect", and should read like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewPreview, , "Volgnr=" & Me.IDDefect
```

Note the use of acViewPreview. And the editor SHOULD have suggested this contant.

Also, if Volgnr a number type column, or a string/text? You have to check this in the table designer.

If Volgnr is a text data type, then that line of code has to become this:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewPreview, , "Volgnr = '" & Me.IDDefect & "'"
```

note the requirement to surround the value with quotes.

So in summary:

```
check and use acViewPreview
force the record to be written to the table before you launch report
if you don't' write the record, then the report will show values not yet updated
check if the data type is a number/long/integer type or a text column
if a text column, then surround the value with quotes.
```